# R package ggeffects does not print predictions for all categories

Tags: r

I have a `glmer()` model with a categorical predictor that has twelve levels. When I print the `summary()`, it has all twelve levels.

```
> model.contcons <- data %>%
    glmer(bin_choice ~ Wshort + (1|id), data = ., family = binomial, control = glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))

> coef(summary(model.contcons))
                     Estimate Std. Error     z value      Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)      -1.844979105 0.08002527 -23.0549555 1.311832e-117
Wshortcutwelfare  0.028561627 0.10428477   0.2738811  7.841760e-01
Wshortdiscipline -0.349133890 0.11034237  -3.1640963  1.555653e-03
Wshortfreedom    -0.003641179 0.10245239  -0.0355402  9.716490e-01
WshortineqincOK   0.107650142 0.10173642   1.0581278  2.899972e-01
Wshortleader      0.125679107 0.10041647   1.2515786  2.107235e-01
Wshortpolice      0.217560461 0.10133894   2.1468595  3.180447e-02
Wshortpolitduty   0.177802391 0.09991568   1.7795244  7.515383e-02
Wshortrefugees    0.109247617 0.10508525   1.0396094  2.985214e-01
WshortRussia      0.115529761 0.10101235   1.1437192  2.527401e-01
Wshorttaxesdown   0.176320660 0.10252782   1.7197347  8.548067e-02
Wshortworse-off  -0.016075802 0.10455777  -0.1537504  8.778065e-01
```

But for some reason, using `ggeffects` functions (`ggpredict()` or `ggemmeans()`) only print eight.

```
> ggemmeans(model.contcons, "Wshort [all]")
# Predicted probabilities of bin_choice

Wshort     | Predicted |       95% CI
-------------------------------------
climate    |      0.14 | [0.12, 0.16]
cutwelfare |      0.14 | [0.12, 0.16]
freedom    |      0.14 | [0.12, 0.15]
ineqincOK  |      0.15 | [0.13, 0.17]
leader     |      0.15 | [0.13, 0.17]
politduty  |      0.16 | [0.14, 0.18]
refugees   |      0.15 | [0.13, 0.17]
worse-off  |      0.13 | [0.12, 0.15]
```

How do I get all twelve? I can't see any parameter that limits what's printed in the help, nor any limits to how many categories a predictor may have. The ones dropped don't even appear to be in any particular order, so why specifically these four (discipline, police, Russia, taxesdown) are missing?

Googling ggeffects and categories didn't help either. I know how to calculate marginal means manually, but `ggeffects` would be so handy.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Is the problem simply a matter of printing more rows? As in `ggemmeans(model.contcons, "Wshort [all]") %>% print(n = 12)`? Hard to know without having some of the data, e.g. `dput(data)` or `dput(head(data, N))`, where `N` is some integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's obscure, but under `?as.data.frame.ggeffects`:

> *Printing Results*

> The ‘print()’-method gives a clean output (especially for
> predictions by groups), and indicates at which values covariates
> were held constant. Furthermore, the ‘print()’-method has the
> arguments ‘digits’ and **‘n’ to control number of decimals and lines
> to be printed** ...

(emphasis added).

Using @Ventrilocus's sample data:

Thus

```r
print(ggemmeans(model.contcons, "Wshort"), n = Inf)
```

(you could say `n=12` in this case ...)

```r
 Predicted probabilities of bin_choice
Wshort     | Predicted |       95% CI
-------------------------------------
climate    |      0.48 | [0.36, 0.60]
cutwelfare |      0.62 | [0.51, 0.72]
discipline |      0.46 | [0.35, 0.57]
freedom    |      0.39 | [0.29, 0.50]
ineqincOK  |      0.53 | [0.42, 0.63]
leader     |      0.52 | [0.42, 0.63]
police     |      0.47 | [0.38, 0.57]
politduty  |      0.48 | [0.38, 0.58]
refugees   |      0.56 | [0.46, 0.65]
Russia     |      0.54 | [0.44, 0.63]
taxesdown  |      0.48 | [0.38, 0.59]
worse-off  |      0.45 | [0.34, 0.56]
```

I feel like the function should print a message to let the user know that some levels were dropped ...

As for "why are these *particular* levels dropped/shown?" [This](https://github.com/strengejacke/ggeffects/blob/27edac97a32ed8a718be9218391a50c95ad5f171/R/print.R#LL260C1-L260C50) shows that the print method calls `.get_sample_rows(i, n)`, and [that function](https://github.com/strengejacke/ggeffects/blob/27edac97a32ed8a718be9218391a50c95ad5f171/R/print.R#L239-L253) shows that it is essentially trying to choose *evenly spaced* rows to drop/include ... it's doing the equivalent of this calculation

```r
nr.of.rows <- 1:12
n <- 8
round(c(
      min(nr.of.rows),
      stats::quantile(nr.of.rows, seq_len(n - 2) / n),
      max(nr.of.rows)
    )
)
      12.5%   25% 37.5%   50% 62.5%   75%       
    1     2     4     5     6     8     9    12
```

so rows 3, 7, 10, 11 get left out.

Comment: Wonderful! I tried to find the documentation if there's anything on printing, but apparently I didn't look deep enough. This seems to solve the issue entirely.

Comment: How should we do this? I see @Ventrilocus did a part of the work and you did the rest, is there a way to split the bounty between you?

Comment: The proportional effect of the bounty will be much larger for @Ventrilocus, so please give it to them (I got a "Necromancer" badge out of it anyway) and accept my answer as the solution.

Comment: Thank you, @BenBolker. It would have been acceptable to me also if the entire bounty went to you given that you identified the quid of the matter.

Answer (score 2):

First, we need to re-create the bug (with random data since the data was not provided with `dput`):

```
library(lme4)
library(dplyr)
library(ggeffects)


LEV = c("climate", "cutwelfare", "discipline", "freedom", "ineqincOK", "leader",
        "police", "politduty", "refugees", "Russia", "taxesdown", "worse-off")
n = 1000
set.seed(1)
data = data.frame(bin_choice = sample(c(0,1), size = n, replace = T),
                  Wshort = factor(sample(LEV, size = n, replace = T), levels = LEV),
                  id = factor(sample(1:2, size = n, replace = T)))
model.contcons = glmer(bin_choice ~ Wshort + (1|id), data = data, family = binomial, 
                       control = glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))
# boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
# Your model did fit on the random data, but it generated that warning because the 
# random effects are very small.


coef(summary(model.contcons))
# Estimate Std. Error      z value   Pr(>|z|)
# (Intercept)      -0.092373320  0.2483275 -0.371981794 0.70990640
# Wshortcutwelfare  0.588810204  0.3451396  1.706006155 0.08800693
# Wshortdiscipline -0.061777360  0.3365319 -0.183570603 0.85435033
# Wshortfreedom    -0.362362835  0.3334687 -1.086647296 0.27719271
# WshortineqincOK   0.195027474  0.3362789  0.579957536 0.56194325
# Wshortleader      0.190011790  0.3325108  0.571445449 0.56769773
# Wshortpolice     -0.010810916  0.3209555 -0.033683531 0.97312951
# Wshortpolitduty   0.001401542  0.3274360  0.004280354 0.99658478
# Wshortrefugees    0.315516871  0.3202734  0.985148445 0.32455116
# WshortRussia      0.234023837  0.3197997  0.731782606 0.46430127
# Wshorttaxesdown   0.018265348  0.3333433  0.054794408 0.95630226
# Wshortworse-off  -0.124691185  0.3411175 -0.365537360 0.71471032

ggemmeans(model.contcons, "Wshort [all]")
# Wshort     | Predicted |       95% CI
# -------------------------------------
# climate    |      0.48 | [0.36, 0.60]
# cutwelfare |      0.62 | [0.51, 0.72]
# freedom    |      0.39 | [0.29, 0.50]
# ineqincOK  |      0.53 | [0.42, 0.63]
# leader     |      0.52 | [0.42, 0.63]
# politduty  |      0.48 | [0.38, 0.58]
# refugees   |      0.56 | [0.46, 0.65]
# worse-off  |      0.45 | [0.34, 0.56] # Missing: discipline, police, Russia, taxesdown


table(data$Wshort) # But these levels are present
# climate cutwelfare discipline    freedom  ineqincOK     leader     police  politduty   refugees 
# 65         74         78         85         78         82         97         88         99 
# Russia  taxesdown  worse-off 
# 99         81         74
```

Indeed, `ggemmeans` skipped variables `discipline`, `police`, `Russia` and `taxesdown`. However, as we can see, these can be computed as:

```
ggemmeans(model.contcons, "Wshort [discipline]")
# Wshort     | Predicted |       95% CI
# -------------------------------------
#   discipline |      0.46 | [0.35, 0.57]
ggemmeans(model.contcons, "Wshort [police]")
# Wshort | Predicted |       95% CI
# ---------------------------------
#   police |      0.47 | [0.38, 0.57]
ggemmeans(model.contcons, "Wshort [Russia]")
# Wshort | Predicted |       95% CI
# ---------------------------------
#   Russia |      0.54 | [0.44, 0.63]
ggemmeans(model.contcons, "Wshort [taxesdown]")
# Wshort    | Predicted |       95% CI
# ------------------------------------
#   taxesdown |      0.48 | [0.38, 0.59]
```

Thus, the bug is in the parsing/printing of the output (not in model fitting or estimation). We can bypass it by doing as follows:

```
RES = lapply(1:length(LEV), 
             function(x) ggemmeans(model.contcons, paste("Wshort [", LEV[x], "]", sep = "")))

print(RES)
# [[1]]
# # Predicted probabilities of bin_choice
# 
# Wshort  | Predicted |       95% CI
# ----------------------------------
#   climate |      0.48 | [0.36, 0.60]
# 
# [[2]]
# # Predicted probabilities of bin_choice
# 
# Wshort     | Predicted |       95% CI
# -------------------------------------
#   cutwelfare |      0.62 | [0.51, 0.72]
# 
# [[3]]
# # Predicted probabilities of bin_choice
# 
# Wshort     | Predicted |       95% CI
# -------------------------------------
#   discipline |      0.46 | [0.35, 0.57]
# 
# [[4]]
# # Predicted probabilities of bin_choice
# 
# Wshort  | Predicted |       95% CI
# ----------------------------------
#   freedom |      0.39 | [0.29, 0.50]
# 
# [[5]]
# # Predicted probabilities of bin_choice
# 
# Wshort    | Predicted |       95% CI
# ------------------------------------
#   ineqincOK |      0.53 | [0.42, 0.63]
# 
# [[6]]
# # Predicted probabilities of bin_choice
# 
# Wshort | Predicted |       95% CI
# ---------------------------------
#   leader |      0.52 | [0.42, 0.63]
# 
# [[7]]
# # Predicted probabilities of bin_choice
# 
# Wshort | Predicted |       95% CI
# ---------------------------------
#   police |      0.47 | [0.38, 0.57]
# 
# [[8]]
# # Predicted probabilities of bin_choice
# 
# Wshort    | Predicted |       95% CI
# ------------------------------------
#   politduty |      0.48 | [0.38, 0.58]
# 
# [[9]]
# # Predicted probabilities of bin_choice
# 
# Wshort   | Predicted |       95% CI
# -----------------------------------
#   refugees |      0.56 | [0.46, 0.65]
# 
# [[10]]
# # Predicted probabilities of bin_choice
# 
# Wshort | Predicted |       95% CI
# ---------------------------------
#   Russia |      0.54 | [0.44, 0.63]
# 
# [[11]]
# # Predicted probabilities of bin_choice
# 
# Wshort    | Predicted |       95% CI
# ------------------------------------
#   taxesdown |      0.48 | [0.38, 0.59]
# 
# [[12]]
# # Predicted probabilities of bin_choice
# 
# Wshort    | Predicted |       95% CI
# ------------------------------------
#   worse-off |      0.45 | [0.34, 0.56]
```

To finally parse all this info into a nice output, you can do:

```
RES = lapply(1:length(LEV), 
             function(x) as.data.frame(ggemmeans(model.contcons, paste("Wshort [", LEV[x], "]", sep = ""))))
RES = Reduce(rbind, RES)
```

Comment: It's a good effort, but it's more of a documentation bug/obscurity than an actual code bug ...